# Dealing with large files

Tags: .net, f#

I have a large log file that I need to parse with F# on Windows 8. A server is constantly running that writes to the end of the log file by adding new lines. The log files are checked every minute for changes. Instead of reparsing the entire file, I would rather just read from the end and combine the newly added lines to the result of the previous parse. Better yet, I'd like to just be able to register a callback for whenever the file is changed. Is that possible?

Comment: Of course, ideally, it would be best if you could just reconfigure the server that writes to the end of the log file to also write to some service you expose (if the server is using log4net or even the Trace api, shouldn't be too hard)...

Comment: Yeah, that would be nice. Unfortunately, the server is just a .exe that I don't have the source for.

Comment: You may use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) for triggering your handler. The handler, in turn, would remember the last accessed offset (or just previous file size), then `Seek()` there and read the new lines. Pay your attention to opening the file properly so that there were no access conflicts. It also depends on how the server opens the file for writing.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198841/getting-new-lines-from-a-file-with-filesystemwatcher

Answer (score 1):

You can do this be `Seek()`ing through the filestream. Something like this:

```
open System.IO

let WatchLog directory file =
    // Keep track of last read position
    let lastRead = ref 0L

    // Function that's called whenever the file changes
    let processLog (e : FileSystemEventArgs) =
        // Open file, and seek to the last read location
        use fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(directory, file), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        fs.Seek(!lastRead, SeekOrigin.Begin) |> ignore

        // Read the rest of the file
        use sr = new StreamReader(fs)
        printfn "Reading log: %A" (sr.ReadToEnd())

        // Store the length so that we know how much to seek over next time
        lastRead := fs.Length
        ()

    // Create a FS watched to be notified when a file changes
    let fs = new FileSystemWatcher(directory, file)
    fs.Changed.Add(processLog)
    fs.EnableRaisingEvents <- true

WatchLog "M:\Coding\" "TestLog.txt"
```

However, for some reason, on my machine I get "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another proc" errors, which I can't track down. The `use` statements should be disposing when they go out of scope, and even explicit calls to `Close` doesn't fix it :/

Comment: If you're doing this from different threads or processes, then I would expect that message. Adding one more parameter at the end - ", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite) - will perhaps fix it. But the writer must also share. (I haven't tested anything.)